# Failed to execute a function in event Listener

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have just started programming and I am trying to do a quiz, but function is not working. Problem reads as follows and its not reading function handlefirst()

scripts.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.

```
buttonFq.addEventListener('click', handleFirst ())
    
const RespuestaIncorrecta = 'Tu respuesta es incorrecta'

const curiosityFirstQcontent = document.querySelector.innerTex("#curiosity-first-q");


function handleFirst() {
    if(firstqq === "Stallone"){
        return curiosityFirstQcontent = 'Correct'
    }
    else{
        return 'Not correct'
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `buttonFq.addEventListener('click', handleFirst ())` to `buttonFq.addEventListener('click', handleFirst)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument you are passing is wrong. It should be

```
buttonFq.addEventListener('click', handleFirst)
```

And also there is a typo instead of **innerText** in your code it is **innerTex**.Please change this too

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are absolutely correct! Thank you so much, its the simple things that are hard to see at first sight!